# how to send instruction to server every five second

Tags: java, json, sockets, udp

I have written part of the code which server will receive instruction from the client and send request back to the client. 
But I want to send the instruction(Json message) from the client every five second. How could I do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ParseException {

    SynchronisedFile fromFile = null;
    fromFile=new SynchronisedFile("file.txt");
    fromFile.CheckFileState();
    int counter = 1;
    int receivedCounter = 1;
    String receivedType=null;

    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

    while(true){

        Instruction inst = fromFile.NextInstruction();
        //System.out.println(inst.ToJSON());

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("type", "inst");
        jo.put("inst", inst.ToJSON());
        jo.put("counter", counter);
        //System.out.println(jo);
        counter++;

        sendData = jo.toString().getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 4144);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String receivedMessage = new String(receivePacket.getData());

        String subReceivedMessage = receivedMessage.trim();

        final JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject obj;
        obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(subReceivedMessage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Here is a basic example using a returned result using (`Callable`) below. If you don't need the result back you can use `Runnable` method instead with a similar signature:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
ScheduledFuture<String> scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Result";
    }
}, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: If this is what you are looking for make sure to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in Quartz API interface http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ and quick start: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start